# Nodejs Websocket server (using ws) won't run securely

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, websocket

I'm currently running a websocket server on a secure domain (with ssl) but for some reason I cannot get the server to actually use wss instead of ws.

The code below is how I create the Websocket server.

```js
const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync(`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem`, 'utf8'),
    key: fs.readFileSync(`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem`, 'utf8'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem`, 'utf8'),
})

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: [port],
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    server: httpsServer,
})

wss.on('connection', (ws: ExtraWS, req) => {
    ws.id = [id]
    ws.send(`Connected to: ${req.socket.remoteAddress}:${req.socket.remotePort}`)

    ws.on('message', msg => {
        ws.send(`Recieved: '${msg}'`)
    })
})
```

For whatever reason this socket is only available at `ws://example.com:[port]`, instead of `wss://example.com:[port]`. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here please let me know.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but in my experience it's much more convenient to use a reverse proxy like Nginx to handle HTTPS for you and only use HTTP in the implementation.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Thats actually a good idea and I don't know why I didn't just do that.. I used nginx to reverse proxy my backend and frontend but just didn't think to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. The issue was that I was specifying the port in the Socket server instead of specifying it in the httpsServer.listen().

This is the amended code:

```js
const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync(`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem`, 'utf8'),
    key: fs.readFileSync(`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem`, 'utf8'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem`, 'utf8'),
})

httpsServer.listen([port])

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    server: httpsServer,
})
```